# Can I make a taxonomy meta box into dropdowns for each parent category?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

It's possible there's a better way to handle this content, but here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a listings site with a huge amount of terms for a custom taxonomy--around 450. It will be incredibly difficult to wade through all those terms when adding new posts. I need a way to list the taxonomy terms in a way that is easier to scroll through.

I'd like to make the categories into accordion-style dropdowns, where every parent term is turned into an accordion/link, so that at first, only the parent terms are listed.

Then, when you click a parent term, all the child terms open.

I am not sure if this is possible (without a ton of work) or if there are better alternatives. So far, I haven't found much for altering the taxonomy meta box beyond changing the select type to radio/dropdown, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to dive in the `wp_dropdown_categories( $args );` and `wp_list_categories` functions to list your terms, even if I don't think it's the better way. For accordion you will need to compose your own select and option entries and use your own css/js like [Smooth accordion dropdown menu](https://codepen.io/fainder/pen/AydHJ).

It's possible to list term hierarchically with `wp_dropdown_categories( $args );`.

the list of args to change as you want :

```
$args = array(
    'show_option_all'    => '',
    'show_option_none'   => '',
    'option_none_value'  => '-1',
    'orderby'            => 'ID',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'show_count'         => 0,
    'hide_empty'         => 1,
    'child_of'           => 0,
    'exclude'            => '',
    'include'            => '',
    'echo'               => 1,
    'selected'           => 0,
    'hierarchical'       => 1,
    'name'               => 'cat',
    'id'                 => '',
    'class'              => 'postform scrollable-menu',
    'depth'              => 0,
    'tab_index'          => 0,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'hide_if_empty'      => false,
    'value_field'        => 'term_id',
);
wp_dropdown_categories($args);
```

To make the select dropdown scrollable,

```
.scrollable-menu {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Hope it helps you !